# python data formatting in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I get this flow of data from database. but I couldn't figure out how to format it. this is how I want it;

```
This is how it is.
[{'date': datetime.date(2023, 5, 27), 'pnl': '69'}, {'date': datetime.date(2023, 7, 23), 'pnl': '81'}, {'date': datetime.date(2023, 9, 12), 'pnl': '67'} ]
```

```
This is how I want it
[[69, 27, 5, 2023],[81, 23, 7, 2023],[67, 12, 9, 2023]]
[0] = pnl, [1] = date, [2] = month, [3] = year
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that, since that would mean that you lose context, it makes it unclear what the first, second, etc. items are.

If you really want to do this, you can post-process the data with:

```
[
    [datum['pnl'], datum['date'].day, datum['date'].month, datum['date'].year]
    for datum in my_list
]
```

with *`my_list`* the list you process.

Typically a *serializer* is used to convert data to a JSON blob and then pass it for example to some JavaScript.